# Shuffle doesn't change the order

Tags: php, shuffle

I have got an RSS feed via `Simple XML`.
I have changed it from `arrays`/`objects` to all `array`.

I wanted to shuffle the output to be in a random order, but for some reason it is always in date based order.

My code below as well as my `print_r` statement

**PHP**

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file($feed);
$order = 1;
$videoFeed   = json_decode(json_encode(array($xml)), true); 
if ($order == 1) {
    shuffle ( $videoFeed );
}
print_r($videoFeed);
```

**Print_r($videoFeed)**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [link] => Array
                (
                    [@attributes] => Array
                        (
                            [rel] => self
                            [href] => https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?playlist_id=PLx0GbZ0m42LqeIybI2x_bBLGlo85-5VNg
                        )

                )

            [id] => yt:playlist:PLx0GbZ0m42LqeIybI2x_bBLGlo85-5VNg
            [title] => Best Joomla! Videos
            [author] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Eoin Oliver
                    [uri] => https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCGkX76DCQlWTdjP3CWNbC-A
                )

            [published] => 2019-06-28T17:37:33+00:00
            [entry] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => yt:video:fouYgPJR5Jc
                            [title] => JD19AT  - Optimizing the Joomla back-end
                            [link] => Array
                                (
                                    [@attributes] => Array
                                        (
                                            [rel] => alternate
                                            [href] => https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fouYgPJR5Jc
                                        )

                                )

                            [author] => Array
                                (
                                    [name] => J and Beyond e.V.
                                    [uri] => https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCy6ThiEDnalZOd_pgtpBk1Q
                                )

                            [published] => 2019-03-30T16:25:40+00:00
                            [updated] => 2019-04-09T20:16:34+00:00
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => yt:video:70Kx00H_cLI
                            [title] => JD19AT  - KEYNOTE - Introducing Joomla 4 for Content Creators
                            [link] => Array
                                (
                                    [@attributes] => Array
                                        (
                                            [rel] => alternate
                                            [href] => https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=70Kx00H_cLI
                                        )

                                )

                            [author] => Array
                                (
                                    [name] => J and Beyond e.V.
                                    [uri] => https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCy6ThiEDnalZOd_pgtpBk1Q
                                )

                            [published] => 2019-03-30T08:55:39+00:00
                            [updated] => 2019-04-29T13:10:49+00:00
                        )
~
```

The feed works, but it is always in the same order.  Have I misunderstood the `$shuffle` function?

Comment: `if ($order = 1)` should be `if ($order === 1)`. But that won't cause your issue. Also, what does `$videoFeed` contain?

Comment: Yes, order isn't actually in my code it's dynamically set by the user.  But I added that to avoid comments suggesting that was the answer.  Looks like I still made comments ha ha.  Whoops.  Corrected thanks.

Comment: `$videoFeed` ionly has one element, the value of `$xml`. Shuffling an array with 1 element doesn't do anything.

Comment: @Eoin He's not talking about the line `$order == 1`, he's talking about the `if` statement. It's assigning with `=` instead of testing with `==`.

Comment: What's the point of  calling `json_decode` and `json_encode`? It's essentially the same as doing `$videoFeed = array($xml);`

Comment: Whoops thanks @Barmar.  I have corrected that, thanks

Comment: @Barmar I did that because `array($xml)` wasn't working for me. I think it was something to do with the way `simple_xml` works.  That's a lot shorter if that works I'd prefer it.

Comment: @JohnConde I have updated my question with the print_r

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're adding an extra level of array container to your data when you write `array($xml)`. So there's only one element in `$videoFeed`, and reordering that has no effect.

Try

```
$videoFeed   = json_decode(json_encode($xml), true);
```

Then the problem is that the feed items are not the top level of this data, they're in the `entry` element of the array. So you should do:

```
if ($order == 1) {
    shuffle($videoFeed['entry']);
}
```

To avoid the overuse of `['entry']` and to avoid problems with `array_chunk` you can move the array up one step.  First make it an array in case you need any parts of the array in the future.  Then move up a step like so:

```
$videoFeed      = json_decode(json_encode($xml), true); 
$videoFeedEntry = $videoFeed['entry'];
if ($order == 1) {
    shuffle($videoFeedEntry);
}
```

Comment: In doing so I get more errors:
Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in /default.php on line 76

Warning: array_chunk() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in /default.php on line 76

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in default.php on line 78

`76:  $arrayChunks = array_chunk($videoFeed[0]['entry'], 4); `
`78:   foreach($arrayChunks as $items) { `

Comment: If I change it back to `json_decode(json_encode(array($xml)), true)` I get Warning: shuffle() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in /default.php on line 69

Comment: If you do that, you need to do `shuffle($videoFeed[0]['entry'])`

Comment: You're adding an extra array grouping, so you have to use an extra level of indexing.

Comment: shuffle() expects parameter 1 to be array & array_chunk() expects parameter 1 to be array & Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: It shuffles with `shuffle($videoFeed['entry']);`

Comment: If you use `array($xml)` then you have to use `$videoFeed[0]`. Everything that wants to operate on the feed data needs the `[0]` index, because you wrapped it in an array.

Comment: I updated your answer as it's easier to show the code in the answer, please correct it if I have said anything wrong.  I think because I was using `array_chunk` later on and I was using the format `$arrayChunks = array_chunk($videoFeed[0]['entry'], 4); ` it was somehow not seeing the 4 as the offset.  By making it a variable it seems to have worked.   `$arrayChunks = array_chunk($videoFeedEntry, 4); ` if anyone know's why that would be excellent.  Thanks @barmar you the man.  And also I noticed how many points you have on here and you've only asked 15 questions, and one of those was a q & a!!!